# Our Wear OS app not listed on the Google Play

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-3.0

So we have an issue with our Wear OS app. Recently we got an email from Google that our app is removed from the Play Store because of quote:

> your app is not compatible with Watch/Wear OS devices due to a conflict in your app’s manifest with the following features: **android.hardware.location.network**, **android.hardware.screen.landscape**, and **android.hardware.screen.portrait**.

But there is no `uses-feature` related to *landscape* or *portrait* in our AndroidManifest, neither in Merged Manifest.

Here is what we have in our **AndroidManifest**:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
```

Any help is more than welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the definitive answer, but are you sure you need the two location uses-feature manifest entries?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603347/1542667

Is there some device you want to filter out, rather than assuming most Wear OS devices will have some form of location available (GPS or network).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah agree. We will submit appeal to the Google if they accepted I will mark your answer as correct one.

Comment: I actually mean just remove the android.hardware.location and android.hardware.location.network lines and try submitting again.